# Can I determine the post that caused a user to earn a badge?

Tags: support, badges

Some badges, like 'Yearling' are associated with a user. Other badges, like 'Great Question' and 'Great Answer' are associated with a post as well.

When I fetch the recipients of the badges, I get a link to the badge and a link to the user, but I can't see any way of extracting a link to the associated post which earned the badge.

Short of walking through every question and answer posted by the user, and filtering them by the rules associated with the badge, is there any way of extracting this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this information is not currently available in the current versions of the API.

It may be added in a subsequent release, it's a little finicky as many badges have no associated posts (or aren't linked to a single post).